# What is the difference between <%# Bind("") %> and <%# Eval("") %> in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have seen bind and eval used interchangeably especially in ASP.NET GridViews. What is the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between <#eval and <#bind in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796685/whats-the-difference-between-eval-and-bind-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Eval is one-way, read only databinding.

Bind is two-way, read/write databinding.

See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

Comment: I got some faster speed gains for replacing the Bind with this syntax for anyone interested:   <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)("comments") %>'

Comment: Consider reading following article prior using `Eval`/`Bind`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623516/The-Evil-of-Eval-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 9):

Bind() is used for two-way databinding.  So when used with the proper type of datasource, it will pull the altered values out of the GridView or other control, and save them back to the database.

Eval() is a one-way, "read only" way to bind the values.