# Server mark error in ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone please tell me where i'm wrong ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComentario_<%# Eval('Id').ToString() %>" 
       TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Error**

`Parser Error Message: Make the server is not formed correctly.`

Comment: Please post your error if you need help with debugging.

Comment: You can't change controlId like that. Use bind event to access your button and change it's id.

Comment: But if I put a `<input type='text'` this should work

Comment: Do you have a public property called "id" in your code behind ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
 <asp:TextBox ID='<%# Eval("Id","txtComentario_{0}") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: With this I got this error: Parser Error Message: The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />

Comment: but why did you need to make your id dynamic ?

Comment: Because the element are inside a ListView

Comment: you dont need to worry about id. listview manages it automatically

Answer (score 1):

The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Bind` instead of `Eval` ,The `Bind` method is typically used with input controls such as the `TextBox` .

Try like :-

```
<asp:TextBox ID='txtComentario_<%# Bind("Id") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Bind indicates two way binding where eval does not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796685/whats-the-difference-between-eval-and-bind-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra information to your textbox, you can add attribute to it.

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("customAttribute", "value");
```