# How to bind/eval a field only for inserting/writing?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I got the difference between Bind and EVal from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259141/difference-between-bind-and-eval). Bind will do both way reading and writing. And Eval do only reading. So any function only for writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no.

**However...**

Some databound controls, such as the `ListView`, support binding in the `InsertItemTemplate`. The insert item template of the `ListView` only writes. Although the binding is only actually used for writing, you still use `Bind()` syntax.

On a related note:

For ther data bound controls, such as the `GridView`, I've had to bootstrap empty dummy data into a row of the data source and tap into the `RowDataBound` event to toggle visibility on my insert and edit command buttons. The read phase of the bind reads dummy data, and the write phase binds values I can use in an insert statement. It is not nearly not as elegant a solution as using the `InsertItemTemplate` support provided by the `ListView`.