# Bind vs Eval in VB.net, What is the main difference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I use Eval there is not syntax error

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeWIL" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" Text='<%#ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(Eval("HaulZoneCodeWIL").ToString())%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

When I use Bind for this statement I am getting an error "Name Bind is not declared"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeWIL" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" Text='<%#ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(Bind("HaulZoneCodeWIL").ToString())%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

How to fix this. I want to use Bind only, not EVAL as Bind is two-way

In the code-behind I am writing like this :

```
Protected Function ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(ByRef str As String) As String
        If str <> "0" Then
            Return str
        Else
            Return ""
        End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
try this way

```
<asp:Label  ID="Label123" **Visible="False"** runat="server"  CssClass="cagText" Text='<%#ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(Bind("HaulZoneCodeWIL").ToString())%></asp:Label >


**<asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeWIL" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" %></asp:TextBox>**
```

see this.. Vb. code

```
  Protected  Sub DetailsView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)        
     Label lablehide=(Label) DetailsView1.FindControl("Label123")
     TextBox _txtHaulZoneCodeWIL=(TextBox) DetailsView1.FindControl("txtHaulZoneCodeWIL")
  **_txtHaulZoneCodeWIL.Text=ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(lablehide.Text)**

End Sub
```

And this methode is wrong. So just change it

```
Protected Function ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(ByRef str As String) As String
        If str <> "0" Then
            Return str       

        End If
        Return ""
    End Function
```

Then just refer this

Eval is one way binding, but  Bind is two way

If you bind a value using Eval, it is like a read only. You can only view the data.

If you bind a value using Bind, and if you do some change on the value it will reflect on the database also

you can see similar post here

[What is the difference between <%# Bind("") %> and <%# Eval("") %> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259141/difference-between-bind-and-eval)

Comment: The bind  is a read only .You can only view the data. That's it

Comment: I am getting error "Name Bind not declared: <asp:Label ID="Label123" visible ="false" runat="server"  CssClass="cagText" Text='<%#ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(Bind("HaulZoneCodeWIL").ToString())%>'></asp:Label >